# Убрать дублирующиеся имена из колонок sql, php

Tags: php, sql

Имеется запрос на вывод данных из базы:

```
SELECT
    shop_type.type_name,
    shop_subtype.subtype_name,
    shop_subtype_subtype.subtype_subtype_name
FROM
    shop_type
INNER JOIN shop_subtype INNER JOIN shop_subtype_subtype ON shop_type.type_id = shop_subtype.type_id AND shop_subtype.subtype_id = shop_subtype_subtype.subtype_id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Нужно, чтобы вывело как-то так:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**При выводе на страницу через foreach:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста написать запрос на sql или скрипт на php, чтобы убирать дубликаты категорий.

Comment: GROUP BY в помощь

Comment: в sql такое не сделать, но можно в php. Вам нужно полученный плоский массив сделать древовидным. В интернете наверняка полно примеров